# Layouts directory in SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have MOSS 2007. I can't find any _layouts directory.

Do I have to create it or do some configuration?

I need it because I have to add a JavaScript (.js) file to it according to this link: http://weblogs.asp.net/wesleybakker/archive/2009/03/05/select-multiple-list-items-in-sharepoint-feature.aspx

Edit:

For me - `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12 directory` has only one folder called bin. There is no layouts directory. Where is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe _layouts folder is the LAYOUTS folder in the `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE` folder.

Comment: please see the edit . there is no template folder in my installation.

Comment: Then your installation is not complete / something went wrong during installation! Did you run the SharePoint configuration wizard etc after installation?

Answer (score 0):

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\Layouts

The underscore is only used in urls.

Note that adding files to the system directly (without creating a solution package) is generally not a good idea.

Comment: for me - C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12 directory has only one folder called bin there is no layouts directory ?

Comment: actually, layouts is under templates - however, 12 should contain about 10 subfolders.