# Sharepoint image content, where was it uploaded?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have this path for an image in an existant Sharepoint website:

```
http://website.domain.ca/sites/DynamicsAx/_layouts/EP/images/logo_new.gif
```

I have deployed the same website to another Sharepoint server/website but I need to reupload the image "logo_new.gif" manually but for the life of me, I can't find where it was uploaded in the first place.

All the pages refer to it as "/sites/DynamicsAx/_layouts/EP/images/logo_new.gif" so all I'd need is to upload it in the new website and it should work.

But where exactly ? I've looked at every lists and collections on "website.domain.ca" and can't find any mention of it. Could not find a physical directory for it either on the SP server.

Any ideas ?

Thanks!

Comment: Everything goes into the database.

Comment: Have you checked the 12 hive?

Comment: Yes the content database, I guess so. But how do reupload it to the new website the same way it was uploaded in the old ?

Comment: Ah, yes. There. It's in: C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\ep\images

So do I just copy it over there or there's a more kosher way ?

Comment: Either you put your image in a document library on your page, or you upload it into a folder of your choice with Sharepoint Designer.

Comment: I see thanks, I'd mark that as an answer, but can't from here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just rechecked. 
The layouts folder is located on the webserver itsself under the path:

`C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE`

So, if you deployed your site on a different server you have to import the contents from there by hand to the new server.

Source:

1. [Layouts directory in SharePoint 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130780/sharepoint-2007-where-is-the-layouts-directory-i-cant-find-it)
2. [How to Access Sharepoint 2007/2010/2013 _layouts folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956448/how-to-access-sharepoint-2007-2010-2013-layouts-folder)

Kind regards

**//EDIT:**
For Sharepoint related questions, you can always hop over to http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com